# Stack in C. Storing pop ant top results

Tags: c, struct, stack

Consider a stack, with a maximum of 100 int's. Defined as:

```
#define MAX 100

typedef struct stack {
    int size;
    int values[MAX];    
} STACK;
```

I have this pop function:

```
int pop(STACK *s, int *x){
    if (s->size == 0) return 1;

    int *p = s->values + s->size--;
    *x = *p;

    return 0;
}
```

Which is supposed to remove values[MAX] last element, store that value at x address and then return 0 if success;

Other functions:

```
int top(STACK *s, int *x){
    if (s->size == 0) return 1;

    int *p = s->values + s->size;
    *x = *p;

    return 0; 
} //like pop function, it should store top element at address x.


void initStack(STACK *s){
    s->size = 0;
}

int push(STACK *s, int x){
    if (s->size >= MAX) return 1;

    int *p = (s->values);
    *(p + s->size++) = x;

    return 0;
}
```

This is my main. It fails only at first pop call:

```
int main(){
    struct stack s;
    STACK *p = &s;
    int i;
    int x,y,z,w,t;

    initStack(p);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        push(p,i);

    int res = push(p,MAX);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("%d|", p->values[i]);

    printf("\nLast insertion: %d",res);

    pop(p,&x);
    pop(p,&y);
    pop(p,&z);
    pop(p,&w);
    top(p,&t);

    printf("\nThe elements %d|%d|%d|%d were removed. Current stack size: %d . Top element: %d.",x,y,z,w,p->size,t);

    return 0;
}
```

Results(only last printf):

```
The elements 1|99|98|97 were removed.Current stack size: 96 .Top element: 96.
```

**For some reason, first pop call fails,** which condemns not only the list of removed elements but also the top element result.
Any suggestions on why?

Comment: what about `push`?

Comment: And *don't* do this: `int *p = s->values + s->size--` please.

Comment: Does the problem only occur if you fill the stack completely? (Please post `push` and `initStack` as well.)

Comment: @EugeneSh.Why? what's wrong with that?

Comment: BTW, `pop` is using `values` and `size`. `top` is using `tamanho` and `valores`. You really need to post MCVE.

Comment: @JohnBauer It is hardly readable and *very* error-prone.

Comment: Any reason you obfuscate the code with explicit pointer arithmetic and not using the index operator `[]`?

Comment: What is `MAX`? Why are you using `100` instead?

Comment: @EugeneSh. edits done. I'm sorry. the variable names were in Portuguese but I translated to make it simple to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second those who have commented about code clarity.  If you are using arrays, you are much less likely to have trouble if you use `[]` indexing instead of pointer arithmetic.

That said, I think the problem is that `pop` has an out-of-bounds issue.  After you push `MAX` elements in `main`, `s->size==MAX`.  Therefore, `pop` accesses `*(s->values + MAX) == s->values[MAX]`, which is actually the element *after* the end of the array.  The array runs from `0` to `MAX-1`, not from `1` to `MAX`.  For example, if `size==1`, you actually want `s->values[0]`, the first element, rather than non-existent `s->values[1]`.

The minimum change would be `int *p = s->values + --s->size;`, but I agree that's not the right way to fix the problem.  Instead, use something like `*x = s->values[s->size-1]; --s->size;`

Comment: why is the second solution better than the first?

Comment: My opinion: because (1) it uses array index operators `[]` for arrays, which is clearer than using pointer operations; (2) it separates the index from the decrement, which is also clearer (and easier to single-step in a debugger!); and (3) it more clearly relates the code to what you actually want to do: get an item (`[]`) and change the size (`--`).

Answer (score 2):

1. You push `MAX+1` elements to the stack since the loop pushes `MAX` elements and there is one more `push` call after the loop.
2. Your `pop` implementation is incorrect because of the line:

   ```
   int *p = s->values + s->size--;
   ```

   The pointer `p` will point to `s->values[s->size]` instead of `s->values[s->size-1]` because the decrement of `s->size` will occur after the evaluation and assignment to `p`.
3. Using increment/decrement operators inside expressions is rightfully considered bad practice and strongly discouraged exactly because of these sort of bugs.
4. When possible, it is much more readable and less error prone to use the index operator `[]` instead of pointer arithmetic like so:

   ```
   int
   pop(STACK *s, int *x) {
      if (s->size == 0) {
        return 1;
      }

      s->size--;
      *x = s->values[s->size];

      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: The last push seems to test the error case, so it's here on purpose.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be the case but I wanted to pointed this out if it wasn't.